# Canceling King Arthurs boosted attack on cards with no effects

Tags: untagged

In Unmatched: Battle of Legends Vol 1 King Arthur has a special ability:

> When King Arthur attacks, you may BOOST that attack. Play the BOOST
> card, face down, along with your attack card.
>
> If your opponent cancels the effects on your attack card, the BOOST is
> discarded without effect.

One of King Arthurs cards is Excalibur. There is no effect on the card just a title. If my opponent plays a card that happens to cancel any card effects would a Boosted Excalibur lose the boosted bonus?

[image: King Arthur Cards]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Jenn S. at Restoration Games

> Essentially, Arthur's special ability is an effect that can get
> canceled, so the Boost would be discarded.
>
> There is some further discussion on it in this BoardGameGeek thread:
> [Feint vs boosted Excalibur](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2283831/feint-vs-boosted-excalibur-game-now).

TL;DR even with Excalibur, the boost would be discarded if an opponent's card discards effects.